# How to turn off the showing of last committer's name and date in new version of Qt Creator 10.0.2

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Whenever I am hovering on top of any line Qt Creator 10.0.2 shows the name of the committer and the date which is disturbing for me:

[image]

Is it possible to turn this off? If so can somebody point how to turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle it in settings here: [image]